# Is there function overloading in Desmos function grapher?

Tags: desmos

My input in Desmos function grapher is:

```
1. f(x,y)=x+y
2. f(x,y,z)=x+y+z
3. f(x,1)
4. f(x,2,3)
```

but it alerts me the following error/warning:

> You've defined 'f' in more than one place. Try picking a different variable, or deleting some of the definitions of 'f'.

Is there a special/unique syntax to note/tell Desmos that I want to overload function `f`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, overloading is not supported. I threw together a hack that may work for you, using a list as input: [Fake Function Overloading](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/voyzlutj84).